# How to Custom RecyclerView onclick change image work like checkbox?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a new Android developer, can someone please give me an example of a  custom recyclerview onclick and change image.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Write this code to create Custom view

```
public class CustomView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomView.RecyclerViewHolder> {


    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView mName, mPhone;

        View mCircle;

        RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CONTACT_name);
            mPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CONTACT_phone);
            mCircle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.CONTACT_circle);


        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // get the single element from the main array
        final Contact contact = Contact.CONTACTS[i];
        // Set the values
        viewHolder.mName.setText(contact.get(Contact.Field.NAME));
        viewHolder.mPhone.setText(contact.get(Contact.Field.PHONE));


        // Set the color of the shape
        GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) viewHolder.mCircle.getBackground();
        bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor(contact.get(Contact.Field.COLOR)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Contact.CONTACTS.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to create pojo class,custom list view , display Activity to display the data and finaly MainActivity